# push an object to an array not working on Javascript react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to build some react app, and in that app Im pushing some objects to an array, then setting this arrray as a react component state.
The problem is that's not working, this is my code -

```
var busArray = []
        if(apiResponse.length > 0)
        {
            for(var i in apiResponse) {
                if("ns3:VehicleLocation" in apiResponse[i]["ns3:MonitoredVehicleJourney"][0]) {
                    var busInfoObject = {"lineNo": apiResponse[i]["ns3:MonitoredVehicleJourney"][0]["ns3:PublishedLineName"][0],
                                                "operatorCode": apiResponse[i]["ns3:MonitoredVehicleJourney"][0]["ns3:OperatorRef"][0],
                                                "lat": apiResponse[i]["ns3:MonitoredVehicleJourney"][0]["ns3:VehicleLocation"][0]["ns3:Latitude"][0],
                                                "lng": apiResponse[i]["ns3:MonitoredVehicleJourney"][0]["ns3:VehicleLocation"][0]["ns3:Longitude"][0]
                                        }
                    busArray.push(busInfoObject)
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log("No busses nearby detected")
        }
        console.log(busArray)
        this.setState({busRealTimeInfo: busArray}, ()=> console.log(this.state.busRealTimeInfo))
```

as you see I try to write the final array to the console to see the result, and I see this strange array that has a length but empty inside -

[image]

does anyone know what is this? and why it is happening?

**UPDATE**
I tried to change the console.log(busArray) to console.log(busArray[0]) and it actually printed the real inforamtion, but still can't push the array into the state and the whole array printed to the console as empty..
[image]

somebody ever saw that kind of problem?

Comment: Can you share the whole code on https://codesandbox.io/ ?

Comment: Try passing static busInfo object `busArray.push({ lineItem: "Here"})` and check if you are getting elements there.

Comment: tried to do that, same problem.. @PardeepDhingra

Comment: can you try this?

this.setState({busRealTimeInfo: busArray}, ()=> 
{
console.log(this.state.busRealTimeInfo)
console.log(busArray)
}
)

Comment: @Siyavash Nothing printed in console..

Comment: Can you upload this class on https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: @Siyavash dont know if its gonna help but here it is - https://jsfiddle.net/arikm9/n5u2wwjg/197415/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fiddle, it looks like you are accidentally resetting the array in the shouldComponentUpdate check.

```
 shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        if (nextState.busRealTimeInfo.length = 0 ...
```

Should be

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
            if (nextState.busRealTimeInfo.length === 0 ...
```